# Can't open cloudera manager

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, data-science, cloudera-manager

I am new in Big data and hadoop, i made a file called test with hello world content and i wanted to upload it into file browser when try this it gives me an error i tried to solve it by searching the answer in this website and i found that the problem is in cluster " cloudera manager " when i try to open it it gives me a message that is highly recommended that use 10 Rams  but if you want to force open use the command force " My PC is 6 g ram and when downloading the system it was recommended 8 g ram bus i give the Virtual machine 5,5 g ram and it is flexible with me in using the system so what is the problem and how can i force start the cloudera manager?

Answer (score 1):

Launch Terminal (black icon adjacent to firefox at the top), then run

```
sudo ~/cloudera-manager --force
```

[QuickStart] Shutting down CDH services via init scripts...

[QuickStart] Disabling CDH services on boot...

[QuickStart] Starting Cloudera Manager services...

[QuickStart] Deploying client configuration...

[QuickStart] Starting CM Management services...

Comment: when i open the the hue give me that no thing  like that when i change the host  open but gives me this error 

    Internal error while querying the Host Monitor

Comment: You might have to start the services. Go to cloudera manager url and see all the services are up and running or not. Above command only starts CM Management services (like host monitor, etc). It might not have started services like HDFS, YARN, Hue etc.